# .NET MVC Shopping Cart

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

What .NET MVC3 (or MVC) shopping cart software is available (open source or commercial)? Preferably with existing payment gateways. I'm only aware of MvcMusicStore. Are there any others?

Comment: Do you really want to loose flexibility by using someone's cart? It's quite easy to implement using MvcMusicStore and gateway which probably will have server file with build in functions translatable to all programming languages.

Comment: Yeah - I'm currently just customising mvcmusicstore. Mvc makes this stuff so much easier. However, I still thought I would throw the question out there to the community.

Comment: @eugenek, its a tradeoff between months of someone else's time that has already developed something open source - tested and implemented nice functionality - and having your own control. Why use anyone else's software then for anything? Sometimes its just easier : )

Comment: Sometimes using such open source, tested solutions is as hard as creating your own but without flexibility to do what you desire. I don't believe shopping cart with connection to gateway ( you need ) taken few month to create. Think about case where open source solution build with A gateway and you cannot apply to A gateway because your account and company is in Europe so you must use gateway B. Then you will need to learn API of open source solution which not always well documented and dig though amount of code that made by others ppl with other ideas.

Comment: sure - sometimes open source projects don't match your requirements...but then you have a long development time for something robust. The packages out there support most common scenarios and for a cart with lots of features there are some great packages. At times you gain flexibility from a nice thought out solution. Its up to you to decide.  As for 'which gateway' you are empowered to research ahead of time what gateways are supported for your region. There are many packages that employ the major common gateways - at least in the usa.

Comment: I dont necc. think 'roll your own' is always the best choice here, and I can bring up many security concerns for the 'common' developer why this can be a bad idea for a payment system.

Answer (score 5):

Download Web Matrix from http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

In Web Matrix you can choose from "Site from Web Gallery" and your options will be plenty. Not sure which are MVC based but check it out.

For some screenshots on getting web matrix (ya - this is eventually for installing orchard, but you'll see the same screens and you can select from the eCommerce section.

inline html diff
side-by-side html diff
side-by-side markdown diff
Download Web Matrix from http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

In Web Matrix you can choose from "Site from Web Gallery" and your options will be plenty. Not sure which are MVC based but check it out.

For some screenshots on getting web matrix (ya - this is eventually for installing orchard, but you'll see the same screens and you can select from the eCommerce section.

Edit: If you really don't think this is helpful - look at the current list of integrated well known shopping carts via the method I supplied. There's a reason I referred you to web matrix as opposed to giving you an opinionated list that potentially gets stale.

[Installing WebMatrix and Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Default.aspx?Page=Working-with-Orchard-in-WebMatrix&NS=&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: @Adam Tuliper - Whining about downvotes is a surefire way to attract more downvotes.  I had to restrain myself from downvoting you on general principle.  Joking.  Maybe.

Comment: @AdamTuliper perhaps because it has 'microsoft' in the URL ?

Comment: @Simon_Weaver so does basically the ".NET MVC" of the OP title : )

Answer (score 4):

[Nopcommerce](http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/) has been upgraded to ASP .NET MVC3 and is very feature rich.

Comment: It's a PAIN to integrate into an existing or new site though...  They hsould have kept it just as a shopping cart plugin not trying to be a full blown whatever it is.

Comment: Would rather roll my own than use it.